# Div Content Fade In, Fade Out

Tags: javascript, jquery

I apologize if this question has been posted once before, I am a noob to jquery, but It seems like I have part of it working.

I have the code partly working, but when you go to krissales.com, it'll load the page twice, if you see what I mean. I just want it to load once, on fade in, and once on fade out, however it does it twice.

Again, I apologize if this has already been posted. I do appreciate your time. Thank you.

This is the code I have:

```
function page_load($href) {
  if($href != undefined && $href.substring(0, 2) == '#/') {
    // replace body the #content with loaded html
    $('#content').load($href.substring(2)); 
    $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() {   
      $('#content').fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }
}
```

the full core is at:

http://www.krissales.com/_lib/_js/core.js

Comment: Are you sure that the page loads twice.Works fine on my machine though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a slow fadeOut, then fadeIn within the callback. You can try hiding #content within the load() method callback, then chaining a fadeIn() as the final method. For example:

```
function page_load($href) {
  if($href != undefined && $href.substring(0, 2) == '#/') {
    // replace body the #content with loaded html
    $('#content').load($href.substring(2), function () {
      $('#content').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: ah, so it was simply a .hide, damn. Thanks alot man. I appreciate you.